# Regex to match last space character

Tags: javascript, regex, asp-classic

I need some help. I am looking for a regex that would match the last space character in a string. I am using JavaScript and classic ASP.

I have a long string of text which I trim to 100 characters. I would like to remove the last character to avoid a spelling mistake if the trim cuts a word due to the 100 characters limit.

```
regex.replace(/[ ]$.*?/ig, '');
```

Anybody with ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should have been more precise about what you’re looking for. “Match everything from the last space up to the end” would fit better.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From my understanding, you need to remove the last space and everything after it, right?

```
 str = str.replace(/\s+\S*$/, "")
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Stereofrog exactly what I needed

Comment: Glad to hear it's working, but Gumbo is right - next time try to be more precise

Answer (score 15):

Try a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead):

```
/ (?=[^ ]*$)/
```

And for arbitrary whitespace characters:

```
/\s(?=\S*$)/
```

Comment: @Gumbo: Am I missing something or is this unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: @dclowd9901: It’s just practice. The more often you use it the more skilled you get.

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, this matches exactly the last space character in a string and nothing else.

Comment: Ah, I've been missing something quite essential, then. :) Nice work, +1.

Comment: Thanks @Gumbo, great regex

Answer (score 4):

That would be

```
/ +$/
```

A space character (), at least once (`+`), at the end of the line (`$`)

Note that putting the space in a character class is unnecessary, unless you want to match more than a space character, for example tabs `[\t ]`.

To really match the *single last space* only, use `/ $/`

---

**EDIT**: To cut off everything after the last space (thinking about it, this is what you *actually* seem to want, you can use:

```
regex.replace(/ +\S*$/ig, '');
```

where the regex means: "At least one space, and any non-whitespace characters after it (`\S*`), at the end of the line (`$`).".

This can only match the last bit of a line after the last space. As a side-effect, the string is trimmed at the end.

Comment: This helps me match all chars in a string AFTER the last space. How can I use this to match all chars in a string BEFORE the last space? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The regex `/^.+ [^ ]*$/` will match only the last space of a line.

Comment: No, this will match the entire line, more or less.

Comment: yes it will, but it specifies for the last space, sorry I was unspecific. A well placed capture group will give you what you want based on this.

Answer (score 1):

Using "classic" REs, what you'd want would be `" [^ ]*$"` -- i.e. a space character followed by an arbitrary number of non-space characters followed by the end of the line. The "non-space characters" might or might not fit your definition of a "word" though -- for example, it'll also prevent you from cutting a number in the middle. If you want to limit a "word" to containing letters, you could use: `" [^A-Za-z]*$"` instead.

Also note that either way, if a word happens to end at exactly the 100th character, this will match the space before it, so you'll remove that last entire word. If you want to prevent that, you'll (probably) want to look at the first character that you cut off, and if it's white space, don't remove anything from the buffer.