# Regex to find last space character

Tags: javascript, regex

**I am looking for a regex that will give me the index of the last space in a string using javascript.**

I was using goolge to find a suitable regex, but no success.
Even the [SO-Question Regex to match last space character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464021/regex-to-match-last-space-character) does not hold a solution because the goal there was to remove more than one character in the end.

**What is the correct regex?**

Comment: You can't use `"str".lastIndexOf(' ')`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I commented I would just use `lastIndexOf()` but here is a regex solution:

The regex `/ [^ ]*$/` finds the last space character in a string. Use it like this:

```
// Alerts 9
alert("this is a str".search(/ [^ ]*$/));
```

Comment: It **does** work in IE. You probably thougt about Array.lastIndexOf which is not supported everywhere.

Comment: The best thing about the regex solution is that can easily be expanded to find the last index of any whitespace character, which I've needed for text processing before, e.g. to prevent splitting lines mid-word: `mystr.search(/\s\S*$/)`. In fact, this could be trivially expanded to find the last character in a string that matches any character class, or combination of classes.

Answer (score 8):

The correct solution is not using a regex at all but the built-in `lastIndexOf` method strings have. Regexes are meant to match strings, not give you indexes (even though grouped matchs may be returned as index+length instead of a string - C-based regex libraries usually do so to avoid unnecessary copying)

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. I have been mentally fixed to look for a regex instead of looking for other solutions, *d'oh*.