# Finding the first occurence of a whitespace at the left side relative to a given position in a String

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a text in a string, say some Lorem Ipsum stuff.
I want to match the first whitespace at the left side relative to a given position.

Example: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...`, `index: 10`

The first whitespace left from index 10 would be the one between `Lorem` and `ipsum`.

The story behind this: I want to break the text at a specific length (svg - no auto break). Therefore I measure only the whole text-length (speed issues) and estimate which position would into one line. Because I want to split at word boundaries I need to find the left nearest whitespace.

Is there any clue with regex which could do something like this?

//EDIT: A word boundary could ofc not only be a space but maybe a tab or something (`\s`)

Comment: `str.lastIndexOf(" ", 10)` ?

Comment: wow - that was easy. I did not know the second parameter of lastIndexOf. What would I do when I want to catch every `\s` instead of only spaces?

Comment: it's complicated to to that with a regexp, but you can replace the left side with plain spaces before using indexOf, and it should still faster to execute than a RegExp.

Comment: `"a man a plan a canal panama".search(/\s\w*$/)` (slice before)

Comment: @dandavis if you pls could explain what happens there? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
//your parameters are here
var originalString = "a really long string to abbreviate";
var maxLength = 15;

//the actual logic that uses your parameters
var str = originalString.substring(0, maxLength);
var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
```

**Updated Answer to Address Your New Question:**

```
//your parameters are here
var originalString = "a really long string to abbreviate";
var maxLength = 15;

//the actual logic that uses your parameters
var str = originalString.substring(0, maxLength);
str = str.replace(/\s+\S*$/, "")
console.log(str);
```

Due credit to the @user187291 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464021/regex-to-match-last-space-character) for that regex.  Give him/her an upvote!

Comment: I edited my question to make clear, that I need to match all whitespaces which would be matched of `\s` in a regex

Comment: Your regex to match the last whitespace is great. Is there a way to match all other consecutive whitespaces one after another? So first the last, second the one before and so on...

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but I'm sure there is.  Not off the top of my head though.  I've now answered two different questions with this post.  I feel like you're asking me to hit a moving target!  Not sure how to get my answers accepted if the question(s) I'm trying to answer keep changing :-/

Comment: I did not change it but expanded^^. Anyway your answer is the right one. Just waited for some more. I asked in case you would know but I found my solution. Thank you!